# CKEDITOR: CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true not working

Tags: ckeditor

I have a div tag in my webpage

```
<div id="editor1" name="editor1" contenteditable="true">
     {!! $post->post !!}
</div>
```

When I click on the content of this div, a `CKEditor Toolbar` appears automatically. **I tried to disable this Toolbar**. I tried the following but could not be able to.

Try 1 :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    });
</script>
```

Try 2: In the CKEditor config file

```
config.disableAutoInline = true;
```

What is my wrong? I am searching at Google, Stakeoverflow for several hours but not finding any solution. May I be helped by anybody?

**Note that:**

In the Page Header I added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/ewt/resources\assets  
\ckeditor\plugins\codesnippet\lib\highlight\styles\magula.css">
```

and in the Footer I added

```
<script src="http://localhost/ewt/resources/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js">  </script>
<script src="http://localhost/ewt/resources/assets/ckeditor/adapters 
/jquery.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Comment: put CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true; exactly after loading ckeditor.js

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, for me it started working when I set the disableAutoInline outside of document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    $(document).ready(function () {
       ...
    }
</script>
```